# MaxHeaderCountExceededException: Illegal attempt to exceed the configured maximum number of headers: 100

Tags: security, jsf, jakarta-ee, https, glassfish-5

I'm required to force HTTPS in my web application so I did the following 2 thing in my web.xml configuration:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>*</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
        <secure>true</secure>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

When I deploy the webapp on glassfish 5 (which is the container where the webapp should run) I get a series of errors as if the application has entered into a loop during the servlet filters chain.

The exceptions I can identify are:

> **UPDATE** the stack is the following

```
[glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2ServerFilter] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=http-listener-2(2)] [timeMillis: 1519314445367] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Unable to push resource identified by path [/demat/svz]]]

[glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2ServerFilter] [tid: _ThreadID=48 _ThreadName=http-listener-2(5)] [timeMillis: 1519314445367] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Unable to push resource identified by path [/demat/javax.faces.resource/core.js.jsf?ln=primefaces&v=6.1.2.NLC]]]

[glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2ServerFilter] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=http-listener-2(2)] [timeMillis: 1519314445367] [levelValue: 1000] [[


[glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2ServerFilter] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=http-listener-2(2)] [timeMillis: 1519144903315] [levelValue: 1000] [[

org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2StreamException streamId=4474 errorCode=REFUSED_STREAM
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2Session.openStream(Http2Session.java:1116)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2ServerFilter.doPush(Http2ServerFilter.java:994)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2ServerFilter.handleEvent(Http2ServerFilter.java:626)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$6.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.notifyDownstream(FilterChainContext.java:952)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.notifyDownstream(FilterChainContext.java:934)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPushBuilder.push(ApplicationPushBuilder.java:367)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.pushIfPossibleAndNecessary(ExternalContextImpl.java:704)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.encodeResourceURL(ExternalContextImpl.java:662)
    at javax.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.encodeResourceURL(ExternalContextWrapper.java:164)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.ScriptStyleBaseRenderer.encodeEnd(ScriptStyleBaseRenderer.java:246)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:949)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1912)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils.renderJsfJsIfNecessary(RenderKitUtils.java:1203)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.CommandLinkRenderer.encodeBegin(CommandLinkRenderer.java:117)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:892)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1903)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:918)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:309)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:918)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:309)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GroupRenderer.encodeChildren(GroupRenderer.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:918)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1905)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1908)


org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.MimeHeaders$MaxHeaderCountExceededException: Illegal attempt to exceed the configured maximum number of headers: 100
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.MimeHeaders.createHeader(MimeHeaders.java:466) ~[nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.MimeHeaders.addValue(MimeHeaders.java:507) ~[nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPushBuilder.<init>(ApplicationPushBuilder.java:222) ~[web-core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.newPushBuilder(Request.java:2609) ~[web-core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.newPushBuilder(RequestFacade.java:1167) ~[web-core.jar:?]
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getPushBuilder(ExternalContextImpl.java:728) ~[javax.faces.jar:2.3.2]
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.pushIfPossibleAndNecessary(ExternalContextImpl.java:701) ~[javax.faces.jar:2.3.2]
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.encodeResourceURL(ExternalContextImpl.java:662) ~[javax.faces.jar:2.3.2]
    at com.sun.faces.el.ResourceELResolver.getValue(ResourceELResolver.java:143) ~[javax.faces.jar:2.3.2]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:180) ~[javax.faces.jar:2.3.2]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:208) ~[javax.faces.jar:2.3.2]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:139) ~[javax.el.jar:3.0.1-b08]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:203) ~[javax.el.jar:3.0.1-b08]
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226) ~[javax.el.jar:3.0.1-b08]
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50) ~[weld-osgi-bundle.jar:3.0.0.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHelper$ELEvaluatingInputStream.evaluateExpressionIntoBuffer(ResourceHelper.java:832) ~[javax.faces.jar:2.3.2]
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHelper$ELEvaluatingInputStream.readExpressionIntoBufferAndEvaluateIntoBuffer(ResourceHelper.java:755) ~[javax.faces.jar:2.3.2]
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHelper$ELEvaluatingInputStream.read(ResourceHelper.java:719) ~[javax.faces.jar:2.3.2]
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:179) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.read(Channels.java:385) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:345) ~[javax.faces.jar:2.3.2]
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:178) ~[javax.faces.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:87) ~[primefaces-6.1.2.SIA.jar:?]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:667) ~[javax.faces.jar:2.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580) ~[web-core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:338) ~[web-core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[web-core.jar:?]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100) ~[primefaces-6.1.2.SIA.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250) ~[web-core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) ~[web-core.jar:?]
```

Comment: And when you set it to 500? And 600? 1000?

Comment: @Kukeltje I removed the updates because I just realized the test I was doing where not correct. I'm getting the same `...to exceed the configured maximum number of headers: 100`.

Answer (score 4):

Since JSF 2.3, CSS/JS resources will automatically be [pushed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2_Server_Push) to server when both server and client support HTTP/2 protocol and connection goes over SSL (HTTPS). You can clearly see this back in class and method names of this part of the stack trace:

```
at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.pushIfPossibleAndNecessary(ExternalContextImpl.java:704)
at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.encodeResourceURL(ExternalContextImpl.java:662)
at javax.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.encodeResourceURL(ExternalContextWrapper.java:164)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.ScriptStyleBaseRenderer.encodeEnd(ScriptStyleBaseRenderer.java:246)
```

However, in your specific case, the JSF page in question apparently has so many CSS/JS resources that it exceeds the server-configured limit of 100 response header entries.

> org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.MimeHeaders$MaxHeaderCountExceededException: Illegal attempt to exceed the configured maximum number of headers: 100

Given these facts, there are several solutions:

1. Decrease the amount of CSS/JS resources. Frankly, ~100 CSS/JS resources is insane. Consider combining them, if necessary with help of [OmniFaces `CombinedResourceHandler`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CombinedResourceHandler).
2. Configure GlassFish to allow more than 100 headers. This can be done via `asadmin` in commandline. Below is an example which increases it to 200 and assumes that the name of the HTTP listener being used is `http-listener-1` (you can also find it in Admin console app).

   ```
   set configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.max-response-headers=200
   ```
3. Explicitly disable pushing CSS/JS resources by the below Mojarra-specific trick.

   ```java
   @FacesConfig
   @ApplicationScoped
   public class Config {

       @Inject
       private FacesContext context;

       public void viewInitialized(@Observes @Initialized(ViewScoped.class) UIViewRoot view) {
           context.getAttributes().put("com.sun.faces.ExternalContextImpl.PUSH_SUPPORTED", false);
       }

   }
   ```

   This is indeed somewhat hacky, but that's because there's no explicit support for disabling this via e.g. a `web.xml` context parameter. Note that `@FacesConfig` is necessary in order to be able to `@Inject` the `FacesContext`, and that it suffices to have only one annotation of it application-wide. Otherwise you can still grab `FacesContext#getCurrentInstance()`.

Comment: I'm having at most 48 resources loaded per page request. about 18 CSS and the rest is JS. I read that there has been an issue with the nucleus-grizzly-all.jar module when using HTTP/2. Though I have version 5 of this module in Glassfish 5. Not sure if in this version it should have been fixed already or not.

Comment: unfortunately the setting you proposed is not working. It is solved though disabling HTTP/2. I wouldn't like to disable it though. Any Ideas?

Comment: @500Servererror: 3 different solutions were proposed and you talk about **THE** setting. See my other comment on your answer

Comment: @Kukeltje I'm using Primefaces and the resources loaded by the browser are definitely less than 100. Unfortunatelly I'm on a tight schedule and I can't try to add OmniFaces to my applications not knowing if it can coexist with Primefaces. The third slution proposed I didn't try. I'm going to implement that later on this day and comment with the results.

Comment: Apparently two headers are set per resource. I don't know the implementation specifics here. As to provided solutions not working, it's helpful to describe "not working" in developer's terms not in enduser's terms.

Comment: @BalusC I thought I was setting the parameter correctly, but I'm I'm still getting the same: `org.glassfish.grizzly.http.util.MimeHeaders$MaxHeaderCountExceededException: Illegal attempt to exceed the configured maximum number of headers: 100`

Comment: @BalusC by trying out your third proposed solutions I am able to browse between pages in my webapp but in some cases I still get the '... maximum number of headers: 100' exception. How can I state my question so that it can be easier to understand? :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by disabling HTTP/2. For some reason, the number of resources pushed to the browser doesn't matter but for so long as I kept HTTP/2 enabled it was creating the above mentioned errors (those mentioned in the question).

To disable HTTP/2 execute the following command in asadmin:

> `> asadmin set server.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-2.http.http2-enabled=false`

Or in your *domain.xml*

```
<protocol name="http-listener-2" security-enabled="true">
  <http http2-enabled="false" max-connections="250" compression="on" default-virtual-server="server">
    <file-cache></file-cache>
  </http>
      <ssl classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.GlassfishSSLImpl" cert-nickname="s1as"></ssl>
</protocol>
```

Comment: How did you reduce the number of resources? How did you check they were actually reduced?

Comment: I didn't reduce it. I tried two workarounds. 1 was that suggested by BalusC to increment the max allowed headers but nothing changed in my application. I continued to have my exceptions. The second thing I did was disabeling the HTTP/2 protocol. This solved my problem. Looking at the resources my browser loads I can say there are at most 56 between CSS and JS (and images). So I suppose the number of resources is not the issue.

Comment: When you increased it, the amount in the error increase to  (So you know for sure that the changes were picked up)? Simple but **important** info. Did you try increasing it to e.g.10000?

Comment: @Kukeltje I can try. I'll report back with the results!